# How can I embed properties of an object type into another object type?

Tags: typescript

I have a type that inherits all the properties of one type and adds some more:

```
export type Displace = {
  piece: nt.Piece,
  orig: nt.Pos,
  dest: nt.Pos
}

export type DisplaceEffectView = {
  piece: nt.Piece,
  orig: nt.Pos,
  dest: nt.Pos,
  start: number,
  duration: number,
  i: number
}
```

I want to write it something like this:

```
export type EffectView<A> = {
    [keys of A]: [values of A],
    start: number,
    duration: number,
    i: number
}
```

How can I embed properties of an object type into another object type?

Comment: Just use `&`? `export type EffectView<A> = A & {
    start: number,
    duration: number,
    i: number
}`

Comment: Are you aware of [intersections](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) and just don't want to use one?  If so, please elaborate about why, hopefully with use cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `interface` you can use `extends`, which reads nicely.

```
export interface Displace {
  piece: nt.Piece,
  orig: nt.Pos,
  dest: nt.Pos
}

export interface DisplaceEffectView extends Displace {
  start: number,
  duration: number,
  i: number
}
```

---

Or if you want to stick with type aliases, you can use the intersection operator `&`.

```
export type Displace = {
  piece: nt.Piece,
  orig: nt.Pos,
  dest: nt.Pos
}

export type DisplaceEffectView = Displace & {
  start: number,
  duration: number,
  i: number
}
```

Using intersections would let you make the `EffectView<A>` generic with something like:

```
export type EffectView<A> = A & {
    start: number,
    duration: number,
    i: number
}

export type DisplaceEffectView = EffectView<Displace>
```

[Read more on both these approaches here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#interfaces)